# Getting information from an XML object in PHP

Tags: php, xml, object, parsing, simplexml

I am using some XML parser to get some information from API, blah blah... :)

In one place in my script, I need to convert string to int but I'm not sure how...

Here is my object:

```
object(parserXMLElement)#45 (4) {
  ["name:private"]=>
  string(7) "balance"
  ["data:private"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "11426.46"
  }
  ["children:private"]=>
  NULL
  ["rows:private"]=>
  NULL
}
```

I need to have this string "11426.46" stored in some var as integer.
When I echo `$parsed->result->balance` I get that string, but if I want to cast it as int, the result is: 1.

Please help!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `some XML parser` & `parserXMLElement` don't ring a bell, care to share which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an object, intval of an object will always be 1(if it doesnt have a __toString() magic method defined).
you can intval SimpleXMLElement and it will return 11426, but to do that, the data member of the parserXMLElement class has to be public. you might need to define a getData() method for the parserXMLElement class or make the data member public.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php). For example:

```
echo intval($parsed->result->balance);
```

will output the value as an integer - assuming that `balance` is a string.

Comment: @errata - see @kgb's answer. I assumed that `balance` was a string